# random 2 vowels using Excel using the LET function

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to generate a 2-character string with random vowel (e.g, ie, oo, au) using the LET function.

I tried the following formula with does not work.

`=LET(a,{"a","e","i","o","u"},x,CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,5),a),y,CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,5),a),x&y)`

Comment: Try =LET(x,{"a";"e";"i";"o";"u"},INDEX(x,RANDBETWEEN(1,5))&INDEX(x,RANDBETWEEN(1,5)))

Comment: @patkim Thank you very much.  It works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LET with INDEX & RANDBETWEEN to generate the result.

In versions of Excel supporting LET function, use

```
=LET(x,{"a";"e";"i";"o";"u"},INDEX(x,RANDBETWEEN(1,5))&INDEX(x,RANDBETWEEN(1,5)))
```

LET assigns the array to variable x and INDEX fetches a random value from x at position 1 thru 5.

[image]

LET function help here. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999